# virtualenvでpythonのパスが通りません。

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

環境はubuntuで、python2.7はインストール済みです。virtualenvを使いたくて、
`$virtualenv --python=/usr/lib/python2.7 .`
と入力したのですが、そのようなファイルはありません。と表示されました。
pythonのパスを調べたら下のように表示されました。

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

パスはあっていると思うのですがなぜできないのでしょうか？

Comment: `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 .` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: できました！！ありがとうございます！！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/131435

Answer (score 2):

pythonのパスを調べるのに`sys.path`を使用すると、Pythonのインタープリタのパスではなくてモジュールを検索するパスが表示されます。

Pythonのインタープリタのフルパスを調べるのには、ターミナルでは`which`を使い

```
which python2
```

pythonのプログラムからだと`sys.executable`を使います。

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

`virtualenv`でPython のインタプリタを指定するのに`--python`オプションを使いますが、絶対パスを指定しても可能ですが、必ずしも絶対パスが必要なわけではなくて、python2.7 をインストールしたい場合は、以下の入力で可能です。

```
virtualenv --python=python2 env
```

また、python2.7 の方に`virtualenv`をインストールしている場合（Python3だと`venv`が使用可能）は、オプションを省略できて以下の入力でOKです。

```
virtualenv env
```

`virtualenv`の公式ドキュメントでは以下のように説明されています。

> -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
>     The Python interpreter to use, e.g., –python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter to create the new environment. The default is the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with (like /usr/bin/python)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！！！